# Access to the state of statefulMapConcat outside of Akka Stream

Tags: java, stream, akka, akka-stream

I have a stream that creates a state for some meta information.
The state contains exactly what I need but how I can access the state
after the stream is done (see [statefulMapConcat](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/statefulMapConcat.html).

```
source.via(someBusiness()).statefulMapConcat(elem -> {
   // state
   Set<Elem> state = new HashSet();
   elem -> {
       // change state
       state.add(...);
       return Collections.singletonList(elem);
   }
}
```

I'm aware that I can expose the state and use it as global accessible variable but then I get a race condition in terms on concurrency.
A concurrent hashmap would solve that issue but I hope there is a solution without locking.

Comment: There's no `statefulMapConcat` there...

Comment: Sorry, its fixed

Comment: If you only want the state once the stream is done, that sounds like the use case for a future (e.g. a `CompletableFuture` in Java or the `Promise`/`Future` combination in Scala).  In Java, I suspect you'd create the `CompletableFuture` outside of the stream and use a technique like in your previous question (perhaps using `Optional`) to reify upstream completion as an element in the stream so you know when to complete the future.

Comment: I've wanted this for a long time. In particular, I wish there were a version of `statefulMapConcatMat[T, M, M2](materializer: Creator[M], f: Function[M, Function[Out, Iterable[T]]], combine: Function2[Mat, M, M2]): Source[T, M2]`. This would call `materializer` on every materialization and it would "share" the materialized value. Of course, you'd need `M` to be thread-safe.

Comment: It should also be noted that there's a point at which offloading state management to an actor (which opens up a world of concurrent possibilities) and using a `mapAsync` into a `mapConcat` would be the truly idiomatic Akka thing to do.

Comment: @LeviRamsey That works (and I think that's what I've done a couple times), but it is annoying if you need each separate materialization of your flow to have a separate actor/state.